# An audiobook that explains some physics phenomena with the rigor of a textbook?

Tags: resource-recommendations

Physics books usually use a lot of equations and images, audiobooks can't use either. Is there any audiobooks that describe the mental imagery so clearly that these images and equations are not needed? This is a somewhat person specific question but I'm looking for a book that has worked for at least one person (you). I'm fine with equations, but it would be interesting to know how physics might be precisely explained without them, or only with simple ones. When I try to understand equations that are found in textbooks, I view them in terms of "is linearly proportional to" and "is inversely proportional to" etc. I think these kind of relationships could be expressed in audio format.

Comment: Which particular area of physics are you interested in, (it's possibly likely to find a well written popular science audiobook) or is it a general textbook you are looking for (you are less likely to find this, imo)? _ I'm not shy to equations, but it would be interesting to know how physics might be precisely explained without them._  You might be asking how you make an omelette without breaking an actual egg here.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to self study quantum mechanics. However a book from any field that seems to get away without hard to imagine equations or not so accurate analogies will suffice.

Comment: I am in the  same position, without looking at equations (for a long time), I don't think anybody could truly follow QM. Personally, unless I follow the math completely , and avoid  basing my assumptions on my intuition, I'm always going to go astray.